# Javascript array.length is 0 until I do an alert()

Tags: javascript, scope, alert

I am trying to write some javascript that builds html controls based on the response from a Sharepoint WebServices getList.  I store the controls in an array.  After building the array, the length is 0 until I perform an alert, then it becomes the right number.

```
var controls = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Make call to WebServices to retrieve list data
    $().SPServices({
        operation:    "GetList",
        listName:     qs["list"],
        completefunc: parseList
    });

    console.log(controls.length);           // this outputs 0
    alert("This has to be here to work.");  // this has to be here, no idea why
    console.log(controls.length);           // this outputs 6
    for (var i=0; i<controls.length; i++) {
        controls[i].addControl();
    }
});

function parseList(xData,status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("Field").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("ID") && $(this).attr("SourceID") != "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3") {
            if ($(this).attr("Type") == "Text") {
                controls.push(new Textbox(this));
            } else if ($(this).attr("Type") == "Choice" && $(this).attr("Format") == "Dropdown") {
                controls.push(new Dropdown(this));
            } else if ($(this).attr("Type") == "Choice" && $(this).attr("Format") == "RadioButtons") {
                controls.push(new RadioButtons(this));
            } else if ($(this).attr("Type") == "MultiChoice") {
                controls.push(new MultiChoice(this));
            } else if ($(this).attr("Type") == "Boolean") {
                controls.push(new Boolean(this));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Alert seems to be the only thing that makes `controls.length` work properly.  I can only think that this is some sort of scoping problem.  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: My 0.02: the alert gives time enough to wait for the WS to answer. Check out for async calling and use of callback

Comment: Learn how asynchronous calls work, or set it to synchronous mode and deal with the consequences xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to this asynchronous code

```
$().SPServices({
        operation:    "GetList",
        listName:     qs["list"],
        completefunc: parseList
});
```

The alert stops temporarily the thread execution enough to allow the call of the callback function

So try to move this part

```
console.log(controls.length);           // this outputs 6
for (var i=0; i<controls.length; i++) {
    controls[i].addControl();
}
```

into `parseList()` function

Answer (score 1):

`$().SPServices` is an asynchronous function. The `controls` array will not be populated until  `parseList` is called. Move the loop to add the controls to your `parseList` callback.